# R - How to add a timestamp column to a data frame definition

Tags: r, dataframe

I am wondering is it possible to add a timestamp also known as `DateTime` column to a data frame definition (i.e. append the column post creation); if not what are the alternatives?

***Note:*** timestamp column has not be defined correctly; therefore this code is not reproducible.

```
results <- tibble(timestamp = DateTime?, 
                  comment = character(), 
                  model = character(), 
                  RMSE = double())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this addresses your question:

```
library(tibble)
results <- tibble( timestamp = as.POSIXct(character()),
                  comment = character(), 
                  model = character(), 
                  RMSE = double())

     results
#    # A tibble: 0 x 4
#    # ... with 4 variables: timestamp <dttm>, comment <chr>,
#    #   model <chr>, RMSE <dbl>
```

Comment: library(lubridate) as_datetime(character()) works as well.

Comment: @Viitama Yes, but that requires loading `lubridate`. Is it really necessary? We don't know. It depends on the final goal that the OP seeks. Cheers.

Comment: True, lubridate seems to be tidyverses go to package in date handling, so just wanted to mention it, as he is working with tibbles.